# Exception Handling in C without C++ in Linux

Tags: c, linux, exception

Does Linux provide an exception handling in C without resorting to C++? Or, what might be the best way to implement such an exception handling? The goal is to avoid to check return codes for every function called, but do something like in C++ that is thread safe and easily portable.

Comment: Real men use setjmp()/longjmp().

Comment: Thanks, will check that out. Is there a advantage/disadvantage using setjmp/longjmp over signals as proposed below?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've never heard of Linux providing anything like that, but this page describes a third-party exception handling library for C: http://www.on-time.com/ddj0011.htm I haven't been able to find the download link, though.

Comment: Thanks, meanwhile I stumbled upon the same site, but could not find the source code neither.

Comment: Here, are some general thoughts on excpetion handling and comment on the above implementation: http://landheer-cieslak.com/wordpress/error-handling-in-c/

Answer (score 7):

You can handle the signals by writing your signal handlers for it.
Some of these signals documented at GNU are:

- Program Error Signals: Used to report serious program errors.
- Termination Signals: Used to interrupt and/or terminate the program.
- Alarm Signals: Used to indicate expiration of timers.
- Asynchronous I/O Signals: Used to indicate input is available.
- Job Control Signals: Signals used to support job control.
- Operation Error Signals: Used to report operational system errors.
- Miscellaneous Signals: Miscellaneous Signals.
- Signal Messages: Printing a message describing a signal

You can get more info in depth about this [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Signal-Handling.html).
It states the following which I suppose is what you are looking for:

> If you anticipate an event that causes signals, you can define a handler
>     function and tell the operating system to run it when that particular type
>     of signal arrives.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. Are you aware of some example code that uses signals for expcetion handling?

Answer (score 1):

The kernel does it by using **goto** to jump to the teardown sections.

See here for the coding standards:
http://lxr.linux.no/linux+v2.6.34/Documentation/CodingStyle

Answer (score 1):

Offtopic probably, but I can't resist it, sorry.

I must say, the only really good and comprehensive exception mechanism that I've seen so far is SEH - structured exception handling in Windows.

IT blows the C++ exception handling model (which raises the hands when exception is throw within the destructor of an automatic object during the stack unwinding).

Plus it's a really uniform exception handling, since it combines both software exceptions and those generated by the hardware.

So that if you want exception handling - either write for Windows, or implement something similar for Linux.

P.S. Unlike many people think, exception handling is **far far** more than just interrupting the normal program flow using  `jmp`.

It's also a chain of negotiations about who and how handles the exception. It's (most important) - the correct **cleanup** execution at each scope, dealing with nested exceptions and etc.

Answer (score 1):

May I suggest you to take a look at my library [exceptions4c](http://code.google.com/p/exceptions4c/)? It's been tested on Linux and has many features, such as `finally` blocks, signal handling and a kind of *polymorphism* that lets you create exception hierarchies. It also supports multi-threading.